# Pass extra values to getView onClick method

Tags: android, listview

Sorry just a noob here, my boss handed this to me from the former developer and I don't anything about android. My question is how do I pass extra dynamic values inside `getView` > `onClick` method so that accessible to me.

**categoryCursorAdaptor**

```
class categoryCursorAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public categoryCursorAdaptor(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.specialCatItemName);
        text.setText(data[position]);
        Button Button1= (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnSpecialView);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Access extra values here
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**CategoryActivity**

```
    String[] catValsArr = new String[arrayCatVals.size()];
    catValsArr = arrayCatVals.toArray(catValsArr);
    lvSpecialCatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSpecialCatList);
    lvSpecialCatList.setAdapter(new categoryCursorAdaptor(this, catValsArr));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `position` inside `getView(....)` so use that to get proper data from `String Array`

```
String myData = data[position]; //Use myData
```

under `onClick(...)`

Comment: Sorry can you explain a bit more. I don't have a clue what you just said.

Comment: @DevilRaily You have position inside `getView(..)` method so use that as `index` for getting data from `Array`

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example. Thanks!